# Boost program option having implicit value erroneously aquires value of positional option

Tags: c++, boost-program-options

My Boost program options for my application is as follows.

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;
desc.add_options()  
    ( "logFile,l" , po::value<std::string>(&logFilename)->implicit_value( "trace.log" ) , "Log file name" )
    ( "deviceType,d" , po::value<std::string>(&deviceName)->required() , "Device type" )
    ( "inputFile" , po::value<std::string>(&inputFilename)->required() , "Input filename" );

po::positional_options_description positionalOptions;
positionalOptions.add( "inputFile" , -1 );
```

The problem is that, dependent on position, the `logFile` option can erroneously acquire the value of the `inputFile` option. In the example:

```
./application.exe -d Frobnigator -l /path/to/input/file.xml
```

where `/path/to/input/file.xml` is the input file, not the log file, I get the error message `the option '--inputFile' is required but missing`. No such problem happens when the logFile option appears first, like so

```
./application.exe -l -d Frobnigator /path/to/input/file.xml
```

How can I force this sort of separation between an option with an implicit value and a positional option? Or is there another solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the command line parser has no way to distinguish between these two cases:

1. Implicit option, followed by a value, which is supposed to replace the predefined implicit value
2. Implicit option, followed by a (even required) positional parameter

So, it blindly decides that it will go with case #1. You can still mark end of options by the double-dash - then parser will get the input file name:

```
./application.exe -d Frobnigator -l -- /path/to/input/file.xml
```

I think this logic makes sense because of its simplicity, otherwise it would be too taxing on users to remember which positional parameters are required and which ones aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Having come back to this issue after some time, I believe, this is a bug of the boost `program_options` module. In particular, even, if one sets the parser style to exclude `short_allow_next`, thus to require, that all short options have their parameter directly with them, `program_options` still goes ahead and assigns non-option parameters to a preceding option, if its `max_tokens()` count has not been reached yet, instead of to a positional option.

When looking at the source code of the parser in `cmdline.cpp`, one sees, that there are two places, where values are collected for an option:

1. In the method `finish_option()`, which will assign any immediate value present, but behaves non-greedy with respect to assigning further values from the command line.
2. In the main method `run()`, which greedily tries to assign all non-option arguments to preceding options, that could still accept more values.

Considering, that `finish_option()` works fine and only `run()` later reassigns things in a way, that is inappropriate for implicit/optional value options, there is a workaround by further specializing `boost::program_options::typed_value`: Just make it return `max_tokens()` as 1 on the first set of calls (`min_tokens()` is always called first and `max_tokens()` may receive a variable number of calls depending on whether the `allow_sticky` option style is active, so use calls `min_tokens()` as a reference) and as 0 on subsequent calls. Then the stuffing cannot take place:

```
namespace boost {
    namespace program_options {
        // Optional value, that only accepts values immediately:
        template<class T, class charT = char>
        class TrueOption : public typed_value<T, charT> {
            using base = typed_value<T, charT>;
            mutable unsigned min_tokens_called { 0 };
        public:
            using base::base;
            unsigned min_tokens() const {
                min_tokens_called++;
                return base::min_tokens();
            }
            unsigned max_tokens() const {
                unsigned min = base::min_tokens();
                unsigned max = base::max_tokens();
                if(min == 0 && max == 1 && min_tokens_called >= 2) {
                    max = 0;
                }
                return max;
            }
        };

        template<class T>
        TrueOption<T>* true_option(T* result, const T& deflt, const T& impl) {
            TrueOption<T>* res = new TrueOption<T>(result);
            res->default_value(deflt)->implicit_value(impl);
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

Use as follows:

```
unsigned level;
po::options_description desc("comparebook");
desc.add_options()
    ("level,l", po::true_option(&level, 0U, 1U), "set level");
```